# How to make 3 text boxes on the same line and center aligned

Tags: html, css

I want 3 text boxes aligned LEFT, CENTER, RIGHT along the horizontal axis, and on the same line.

I am able to use `margin-left` and `margin-right` to set a text box in the middle, and then using `position:absolute` and `left:0` I am able to get a text box on the left side (on the same line as the middle box).

Now the problem is the last box, the right box. Using `position:absolute` and `right:0`, positions the box on the right, but it shows one line below.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, and to be honest, I have no idea how `position:absolute` and `left:0` made the element appear on the same line as the middle element.

```css
#sectionM,
#sectionL,
#sectionR {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px outset black;
  padding: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}
#sectionM {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#sectionL {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
#sectionR {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Misha's Homepage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyle.css">
</head>

<header>
  <h1>Hi!</h1>
</header>

<nav><a href="archive/myFirstWebpage/mainPage.html">Archive</a>
</nav>

<article>
  <section id="sectionL">
    This is the left LEFT.
  </section>

  <section id="sectionM">
    This is the mid MID.
  </section>

  <section id="sectionR">
    This is the right RIGHT.
  </section>
</article>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways of doing it. Here is the solution of using `inline-block`, since it's responsive and works well on nearly all browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/kop21mbg/

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}
nav {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
article {
    font-size: 0; /*fix white space*/
}
article > section {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px outset black;
    padding: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<header>
     <h1>Hi!</h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <a href="#">Nav item</a>
</nav>
<article>
    <section>This is the left box.</section>
    <section>This is the mid box.</section>
    <section>This is the right box.</section>
</article>
```

In case you don't want it to be responsive, add the following style.

```
article {
    width: 750px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I am a little confused by your example. In your example html, you're still using the id="sectionL", etc but in your example CSS you don't have these ids. so im not seeing how this is working. The only thing I can think of is that even though there are no ids in the CSS, the html code will work with what it does have (under article > section).

Comment: @user4844024 I just removed them from the sample above so making it not to confuse, the reason is - It's not necessary to use them there, or maybe even in your real project like that. There is a great guide from MDN [Getting started with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started) you will learn a lot from it. Overall `position` isn't a good choice to use in this kind of layout.